# Check if reactive form still have its default values

Tags: angular, forms, angular6, angular-reactive-forms

I am using angular 6 and I have a reactive form with a lot of fields. Some are dropdowns, some are numbers, that by default they have an empty value and some other dropdowns that by default have a default value of `true`.

The user can choose one or all or any random combination of the fields. So I cannot have all the fields as required.

But I have to know if the form still has its default values, so I can cancel the submission.

I tried some checks

```
ngOnInit() {
 this.initialState = this.form.value;
}
submit(){
 if(this.initialState != this.form.value)...
}
```

gives an error

```
submit(){
 if(this.form.pristine)...
}
```

form still may changed back to its default values

I could use some sort of `for` , but I have 8 fields, so its not ideal to loop 8 times before every submission attempt.

So I have to manually check with an `if` like 
`if (!this.form.control.field1.value && this.form.control.field2.value === true ....)` ??

Is there a faster, better way? Just a single check for the whole form ?

Thanks

Comment: Why you don't reset the form and set a default value after submit

Comment: this.initialState != this.form.value will give false , object test by refrence and form.value defrreant object everytime

Comment: What about before submit?

Comment: you cand use form.reset({name:'value'})  so after submit reset the value

Comment: Sorry, I dont get what you said about the `this.initialState != this.form.value` etc. Can you explain further?

Comment: let b = {} , let c = {} , b == c   result false each of them are different reference

Comment: but you can do something like this form.rest(this.initialState) reset the form to initial state

Answer (score 3):

Something like this often works for me:

```
get isDirty(): boolean {
    return JSON.stringify(this.originalProduct) !== JSON.stringify(this.currentProduct);
}
```

I keep a copy of the original object, stringify it and compare it to the stringified updated object.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript object are reference type so even if you declare some variable and assign empty object to all of theme the still point to different memory location and the are different.

```
 var a  = {};
 var b = {};
 a === b ; => false 
 a !== b;  => true but this not valid
```

that why this `if(this.initialState != this.form.value)...` is wrong.

in order to check if the form still have the inital value you have to check each proprty of initialState with each equivalent proprty from form.value it 's look like `initialState.name === form.value.name`

```
let isInitialStateValid = Objects.keys(this.initialState) 
       .map(key => this.initialState[key] === this.form.value[key])  
       .reduce((p,n) => p = p && n);
```

this will make sure if you form still have the initail data

> You can reset your form to the initail state with `reset` method

`this.form.reset(this.initialState);`